# How do I fix inverted movement of mouse?

Tags: mouse

I have downloaded Ubuntu 19.04.

The problem is that the screen looks normal but the movement of the mouse is inverted.

When I used `xrandr` command this would not work with the movement of mouse.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 6):

If the mouse is moving in the wrong direction, but your screen is correct, then you can do the following.

1. Identify the mouse using xinput:

   ```
   xinput list
   ```
2. Once you find the mouse and the line that says `id=X` (where `X` is the mouse id), then do the following:

   ```
   xinput set-prop X "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" -1 0 1 0 -1 1 0 0 1
   ```

Don't forget to replace `X` with the actual number you got from `id=X`.

Here's what I got on my machine for `xinput list`.

[image: output in terminal including "PixArt Dell MS116 USB Optical Mouse id=10"]

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se] and thanks for your answer! Please do not post [screenshots of the terminal](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/8713/250300). Paste the text directly to your answer and apply [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code). You can use [edit]ing to correct this.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can change the mouse behaviour in **Settings -- Mouse & Touchpad -- Natural Scrolling**. Natural "Scrolling moves the content not the view".

Answer (score 1):

These steps solved my issue:

1. Get mouse ID:

   `xinput`
2. Change Coordinate Matrix for Mouse:

   `xinput set-prop <ID> "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1`
3. Get the current Coordinate Matrix for Mouse:

   `xinput list-props <ID> | grep Matrix`